# PHP snmpset multiple OIDs in one packet

Tags: php, snmp

I am configuring a device via SNMP and some parameters need to send more OIDs in one packet (last OIDs has "createAndGo" value).

PHP snmpset can send just 1 value for 1 OID.

How to set multiple OIDs + values in one set frame?

**Below is the example**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the forum and read up on the help centre to find out how to ask a question. We are here to help troubleshoot your code. Please update your question with what you have done and someone can have a look at it.

Comment: improved formating

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to PHP SNMP:set call;

```
<?php
  $session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, "127.0.0.1", "private");
  $session->set(array('SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0', 'SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0'), array('s', 's'), array("Nobody", "Nowhere"));
// or
  $session->set(array('SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0', 'SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0'), 's', array("Nobody", "Nowhere"));
?>
```

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/snmp.set.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use an external program like netsnmp or you work with php snmp class.